# Ubuntu 12.04 overheating my laptop

Tags: 12.04, dell, intel, overheating, bios

I use dell Inspiron 5520 laptop with latest BIOS version A13 with 4GB RAM and Intel core i5 processor.

Recently I have removed Windows 8 and installed Ubuntu 12.04 by disabling the UEFI mode. Since installing Ubuntu I found my laptop overheating. Help me regarding this issue

!! i use AMD Radeon graphic card

Comment: Can you edit your question to include what your graphics card is, please?

Comment: yes AMD Radeon Graphic Card

Comment: its hybrid card Intel HD 4000 & AMD

Comment: update the output of > lspci | grep -i vga < in your question

Comment: after installing drivers for AMD check this link http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681#285681